# Fixing issues with geom_text and axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a barplot in which I need to rotate the bar labels giving the `Freq` values:

```
library(dplyr)
ggplot(df,
  aes(x = partcl, y = Pct)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  # rotate x-axis labels by 90°:
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  # plot `Freq` labels:
  geom_text(aes(x = partcl, y = Pct, label = Freq, angle = 90, hjust = -0.2))
```

But there are two issues: first, the `Freq` labels are not fitted to the plotting area; instead the maximum `Frequ` label (for `yeah well`) is cut off. Second, the x-axis labels are not perfectly aligned with the x-axis ticks. How can these issues be fixed?

[image]

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(partcl = c("yeah well", "well yeah", "yeah yeah well", 
                                "yeah well well", "yeah well yeah", "well yeah well", "well yeah yeah", 
                                "well yeah yeah yeah", "yeah yeah yeah well", "well yeah well well"
), Freq = c(1515L, 408L, 52L, 20L, 17L, 11L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L), 
Pct = c(74.3011280039235, 20.0098087297695, 2.55026974006866, 
        0.980872976949485, 0.833742030407062, 0.539480137322217, 
        0.392349190779794, 0.0980872976949485, 0.0980872976949485, 
        0.0490436488474743)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
        ), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the ticks set `vjust=.5` as by default `theme_grey` uses `vjust=1`. For the labels I don't know of any out-of-the-box option except for increasing the expansion of the y scale:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = partcl, y = Pct)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  # rotate x-axis labels by 90°:
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5)) +
  # plot `Freq` labels:
  geom_text(aes(x = partcl, y = Pct, label = Freq, angle = 90, hjust = -0.2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .15)))
```

[image]

Comment: If anyone figures out a better way than manually adjusting expansion, I'd love to hear it. I perform this task very regularly in my real life data visualization.

Comment: Don't know of a way to expand "intelligently".  Is there a way to assess if something is "clipped"?

Comment: @chemdork123 Yeah. You hit the point. I would guess that the answer is yes. With all the magic one could do with `ggplot2` and `grid` and ... that should be possible. (:

Comment: It's made way more difficult due to the way the plot layers scale differently with the graphics device.  Like how when you resize the window the text does not scale the same way relative to the geoms in the plot.  Definitely not an easy fix in a general sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions in one here to answer:

1. **How to adjust the position of the x axis labels?**  Use `vjust=` and `hjust=` arguments inside `element_text()` to position the text relative to the anchor point.  When rotated, you'll need to fix this (because it's different for how you would position horizontal text).  Use `vjust=0.5` to set the middle of the text to align with the tick mark.  Use `hjust=1` to set the text aligned to the "right" and move it to be next to the tick mark.  Note that your text is rotated 90 degrees, so "horizontal" and "vertical" should be understood *relative to the direction of the text*.
2. **How to show the text above the bar?**  For this, you will want to expand the y axis.  You can do this via `scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult=c(0.05, 0.15)))`.  The vector assigned to `mult=` has two values.  The first value is applied to the lower part of the axis (default is around 0.05, so no change), and the second value is applied to the upper part.  Here we expand by about 15% based on the data (rather than about 5%, which is default).

Here's the code and final look:

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(x = partcl, y = Pct)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  # rotate x-axis labels by 90°:
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.5, hjust=1)) +
  # plot `Freq` labels:
  geom_text(aes(x = partcl, y = Pct, label = Freq, angle = 90, hjust = -0.2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult=c(0.05, 0.15)))
```

[image]